# Delete / Yank lines from current line up to and including line containing search pattern

Tags: vim, latex

Suppose I have the following text (cursor is in middle of first word 'begin.'

```
blah blah blah blah stuff stuff stuff
\\\begin{tabular}
{
|p{0.25\textwidth}
|p{0.2\textwidth}
|p{0.5\textwidth}
|}
\hline
Item & Type & Notes\\\hline
Text text text text text text text text &
Text text text text text &
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  text text text text text text\\\hline

Installation instructions &
.txt / .html / TBD &
Installation help should be conspicuous but not the central item\\\hline
\end{tabular}
blah blah blah more stuff more stuff
```

I want to cut the table out and move it somewhere else. The lines are actually much longer so they wrap several times and I can't easily determine how many lines I want to cut.

I type
<kbd>d</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>/</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>r</kbd>
<kbd>}</kbd>
<kbd>/</kbd>
<kbd>e</kbd>
<kbd>⏎</kbd>
to delete until the second match of "ar}" stop at the 'e'nd of the pattern.

But this grabs from the middle of the word 'begin' to the end of where I want to cut. I'd like to grab complete lines and I feel like there should be a shortcut for this in under 6 keystrokes. I'm not using Latex-VIM because it doesn't like my standard Windows installation of GVIM so no, I can't (as far as I know) easily grab from the `\begin` to the `\end`. I'd love to be proven wrong on that.

---

Yes, this question is potentially a crossover of StackExchange sites including Tex, StackOverflow, and Unix. Feel free to suggest a better site for asking this.

Comment: Well, you seem to know that this is off-topic here. We generally seem to accept editor-related questions only when they have a direct connection to LaTeX in any sense. This is not your case, since, if I understand it correctly, you want to grab whole lines starting where you are and ending at the second match for some string. Anyways, `V/ar}<CR>nx` should do the job.

Comment: Ok, how do I migrate it? Delete and repost there or..?

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, that is the simple answer, but the sequence was already rather long. I was looking for the short easy way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**With an Ex command:**

```
:,/\\e/d
```

Breakdown:

- Structure of an Ex command: `:{range}command{address}`.
- One can use line numbers, marks or search patterns to delimit the range, here we start with the current line, usually a `.` but it can be skipped like here, and we finish with a pattern matching `\end`.
- We `d`elete the lines in that range.

**With a combination of search and contextual marks:**

```
/\\e<CR>
d''
```

Breakdown:

- Search for `\e`.
- `d`elete from here to the line of the previous cursor position.

**With visual mode:**

```
v/\\e<CR>
V
d
```

Breakdown:

- Visually select from here to `\e`.
- Switch to visual line block.
- `d`elete the lines in the selection.

**Variation of the method above with an Ex command instead of a normal mode command:**

```
v/\\e<CR>
:'<,'>d
```

Breakdown:

- Visually select from here to `\e`.
- Enter command-line mode with `:`, the `'<,'>` range is inserted automatically.
- `d`elete the lines in the selection.

Comment: Simple. Eloquent. Amazed. If only verbal languages could be so optimized... I'm having trouble getting it to search for second occurrence of end when there's a nested \begin\end inside.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony, you can do a second search like this: `/\\e/;/\\e` so the  2nd solution becomes `/\\e/;/\\e<CR>d''`, the 3rd solution becomes `v/\\e/;/\\e<CR>Vd` and so on. The `;` offset sadly doesn't work in a range. You should try benjifisher's suggestion, it's really great.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony, correction, you can use more than one search in a range but the syntax is a little bit different: `:,/\\e//\\e/d`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the features you get with the matchit plugin, part of the standard vim distribution.  For testing purposes, do this interactively; if you like it, then you can do this from your vimrc file:

```
:runtime macros/matchit.vim
:filetype plugin on
```

After those two commands (either interactively or during startup as part of your vimrc file)

```
:e foo.tex
```

and then, with the cursor anywhere on `\begin{tabular}`, use `V%` to select the entire environment.  I am not sure whether you will consider it a bug or a feature, but this will include entire lines, meaning that you will get the "\\" at the beginning.

This should also handle nested environments, and commented-out lines, correctly.

Coincidentally, the maintainer of matchit.vim is the same as the maintainer of the standard ftplugin for tex.

```
:help matchit-install
:help :filetype-plugin-on
```

Comment: This only selects from cursor position to the end of the first encapsulation block. In if it's on the `\begin{tabular}` line, it selects to the `}`. If cursor is on a line like `\node [block] (start) ...` in the middle of the word `node`, it selects from cursor to `]`..

Comment: @Okuma.Tony, matchit relies on the filetype of your buffer being correctly set. With `:setf tex`, pressing `%` with the cursor on `\\\begin{tabular}` jumps to the correct `\end{tabular}`

Comment: @romainl Does this depend on latex-vim being installed? I have standard install of VIM 7.4 on Windows 7 and .tex files are recognized well enough to handle automatic indenting.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony:  No, it does not depend on latex-vim.  The matchit plugin is part of the standard vim distribution, in `$VIMRUNTIME/macros/`.  When I refer to the "standard" ftplugin for tex, I mean the one that comes in the standard vim distribution.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony:  In response to your first comment, you are describing the default behavior of `%`, which is overridden by the matchit plugin.  Please pay attention to the order of the commands in my answer.